No PYTHON_UID found for session (random uuid)
I'm facing a strange error when writing a stream from a dataframe coming from Azure Databricks to a Postgres table:
First I use databricks-connect==14.2.1 to connect to create a session for our databricks cluster; below the code snippet:
spark = (DatabricksSession.builder.sdkConfig(__config)
             .remote()
             .getOrCreate())

Second, I read from the databricks table using the deltaSharing protocol with the change data feed option
df = (spark.readStream.format("deltaSharing")
          .option("readChangeFeed", "true")
          .load(my_table_path))

Thirty, I use the above dataframe to create a writeStream job using the micro-batch feature with the foreachBatch method:
    (df.writeStream
             .foreachBatch(process_df18)
             .outputMode("update")
             .trigger(processingTime="30 seconds")
             .option('checkpointLocation', f'{__checkpoint_location}')
             .start()
             .awaitTermination())

def process_df18(df, batch_id):
  # It's not important the method implementation here; the debug breakpoint is not 
    reached here due to the exception that I will be specified after
  pass

When I run the script I always get this error:

No PYTHON_UID found for session (random uuid)

my full dependencies:
alembic==1.13.1
annotated-types==0.7.0
async-timeout==4.0.3
asyncpg==0.29.0
cachetools==5.3.3
certifi==2024.2.2
charset-normalizer==3.3.2
click==8.1.7
colorama==0.4.6
databricks-connect==14.2.1
databricks-sdk==0.28.0
et-xmlfile==1.1.0
google-auth==2.29.0
googleapis-common-protos==1.63.0
greenlet==3.0.3
grpcio==1.64.0
grpcio-status==1.62.2
idna==3.7
kink==0.8.0
loguru==0.7.2
Mako==1.3.5
MarkupSafe==2.1.5
numpy==1.26.4
openpyxl==3.1.3
pandas==2.2.2
protobuf==4.25.3
psycopg2-binary==2.9.9
py4j==0.10.9.7
pyarrow==16.1.0
pyasn1==0.6.0
pyasn1_modules==0.4.0
pydantic==2.5.3
pydantic-settings==2.1.0
pydantic_core==2.14.6
python-dateutil==2.9.0.post0
python-dotenv==1.0.1
pytz==2024.1
requests==2.32.3
rsa==4.9
six==1.16.0
SQLAlchemy==2.0.25
tqdm==4.66.4
typing_extensions==4.12.1
tzdata==2024.1
urllib3==2.2.1
win32-setctime==1.1.0

Any help will be very appreciated and will save my journey.
Thanks.

do you have any column that gentrates UUID in PostgreSQL?

I haven't initiated the database yet, if the problem is within a column in the Postgres table, another stack trace should be in place. PostgreSQL should be enriched in the writeStream, and for readStream, I read from the databricks table path, as I said the function defined in foreachBatch is not reached but when I run the script, I get the output from writeStream in this manner: # df.writeStream 
#     .queryName("toto") 
#     .format("memory") 
#     .start()
# time.sleep(10)
# spark.sql("SELECT * from toto").show(5)

are you using databricks connect in local spark?

Yes I have databricks-connect but without installing spark in my computer OS
